# Grid Skeleton Responsiva com Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Seguinte estou construindo um website que precisa mostrar os posts com o wordpress, porém estou usando o framework de grid Skeleton, ele funciona da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="three columns"></div>
       <div class="three columns"></div>
       <div class="three columns"></div>
       <div class="three columns"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E assim vái....

Mas eu estou tendo o seguinte :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o Problema:

Wordpress tem o seguinte esquema de dar display nos posts:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile?>

<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Como adapto o sistema de grid para a cada 4 posts dar um `<div class="row">` no inicio e um `</div>` no final, para ficar responsivo?

Situação atual:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
        <article class="articlebox">
            <header class="articleheader">
                <h2 class="article_title">Teste Bananinha</h2>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">
        <article class="articlebox">
            <header class="articleheader">
                <h2 class="article_title">Teste Bananinha</h2>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">
        <article class="articlebox">
            <header class="articleheader">
                <h2 class="article_title">Teste Bananinha</h2>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">
        <article class="articlebox">
            <header class="articleheader">
                <h2 class="article_title">Teste Bananinha</h2>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
        <article class="articlebox">
            <header class="articleheader">
                <h2 class="article_title">Teste Bananinha</h2>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">
        <article class="articlebox">
            <header class="articleheader">
                <h2 class="article_title">Teste Bananinha</h2>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">
        <article class="articlebox">
            <header class="articleheader">
                <h2 class="article_title">Teste Bananinha</h2>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">
        <article class="articlebox">
            <header class="articleheader">
                <h2 class="article_title">Teste Bananinha</h2>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias maneiras de solucionar essa questão. Abaixo tem algumas das formas que já usei.

## 1. CSS:

Em vez de usar o framework nessa situação poderá usar o puro CSS. Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

**HTML(gerado pelo WordPress):**

```
<div class=" posts container">
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.posts {
    width: 1280px;
}

.posts .three {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Porém seria necessárias mais algumas linhas de código para corrigir possíveis desajustes no layout.

## 2. PHP:

Você pode também usar uma função para incluir o código necessário no loop, essa era a maneira que eu fazia no início. Fiz uma função exemplo, basta colocá-la no funcions.php e chamá-la na página que quiser:

**Função:**

```
function add_row( $current, $end = false, $columns = 4 ) {
    $row = ( $current % $columns ) === 0 ? true : false;

    if( $row && ! $end ) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }
    if( $row && $end) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

**Exemplo de uso:**

```
if ( have_posts() ):
    $count = 1;
    while ( have_posts() ):
        add_row($count); // Imprimi a tag de abertura
        the_post();
        add_row($count, true); // Imprimi a tag de fechamento
        $count++;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Com essa modificação o loop vai gerar o HTML que você espera.

## 3. Jeet:

Ou você pode usar o [Jeet](http://jeet.gs/) que é um sistema de grids, ele torna a criação de grids css bem mais fácil e rápida.
Mas para isso você também terá de usar um task runner como Grunt ou Gulp e um pré-processador CSS como Less ou Sass ou Stylus. Interessante que dando uma olhada na documentação do Skeleton vi que eles dão suporte a Less e Sass, você pode ver isso [aqui](https://github.com/dhg/Skeleton#extensions). Usando essas ferramentas combinadas* você teria um código assim:

**HTML:**

Séria o mesmo do primeiro exemplo.

**Sass:**

```
@import 'jeet/index';

.container {
  .three {
    col(3/12)
  }
}
```

*A combinação que eu gosto, devido a curva de aprendizado é Gulp + Sass + Jeet.

Comment: Estou utilizando o sistema básico com o html mais o css (gerado pelo WordPress), e está funcionando perfeitamente, obrigado!